# What factors should I bear in mind when choosing between subfiles and standalone?

Tags: standalone, sharelatex, subfiles, multiple-files

[The ShareLaTeX documentation](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects) recommends these two technologies for working with multifile documents.  The documentation says that subfiles is easier to use, and standalone allows per-file preambles; are there any other factors to be borne in mind?

Comment: Standalone is more useful if you want to use the subfiles in several main documents as it is the case for diagrams etc. The sharelatex doc however mentions this as well already.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments?!